# Angular2 - Pass values to a dynamic component created with ComponentFactory

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I was following Günter Zöchbauer's advice on [how to create dynamic components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)
and I was wondering how I could pass values to it - as in, the child component has an @input.

Using the plunker example given in the above question - [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3dzkMVXe4AGSRhk11TXG?p=preview) - how could I pass the child component a string, lets call it message, that would then display when clicking the 'add' button.

Here's an example of how the child component might look:

```
import {Component OnChanges, Input} from '@angular/core'

    @Component({
      selector: 'hello',
      providers: [],
      template: `<h1>{{message}}</h1>`,
      directives: []
    })
    export class HelloComponent implements OnChanges {
      @Input() message:any;

      constructor() {
      }

      ngOnChanges(changes:any){
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try below,

```
  let instance  = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.componentFactory, 0).instance;
  instance.message = "some text!!";
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/2zaASFYyc3kvGRf0PVfx?p=preview)

Comment: I want to pass a dummy data first to show loading screen and then once I get the data from the API, I want to pass it. Is that possible